# Dedicated database server or local database server for performance

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, web-hosting, server-setup

We have a dedicated server that contains 3 virtual server with iis 7.5 on it. There are 50 real ip addresses pointing to the server, with some of them assigned to the virtual servers.

I wasn't sure how to setup, especially where to install the database servers like mysql, mssql server. No I am concerned about performance. Every virtual server has its own local database server. This means 3 mysql server and 3 mssql server in total.

So I thought that if I create a new virtual server dedicated to run these database servers, does the websites face any performance lack according to the local setup? In brief, should I spare a new virtual server purely as database server or should all virtual servers have their own local database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, stop shooting your performance.

- Make a dedicated VM for databases.
- Provide plenty of IO budget - separate disks for the database server. That is disks as plural - I have one database server running on a VM shared image with 8 disks and 2 ssd just for the data - because I need it.